# Why React Native operators behave differently on debug and release builds

Tags: javascript, react-native, operators, release

Does anyone know why operators behave differently on react native (0.54.2) debug and release builds?

This works perfectly on debug. If usageTip is something else than empty string and we are loading first time, we enter inside if and show user the usageTip:

```
if (this.props.usageTip =! '' && this.props.firstTimeLoading) {
    return (
        <Text style={styles.disclaimerTextStyle}>{this.props.usageTip}</Text>
    );
}
```

But on release the if line will somehow set imageTip to boolean value true. What is happening there?

I found a way to get it working on release also:

```
if (this.props.firstTimeLoading && (this.props.usageTip ==! '')) {
        return (
            <Text style={styles.disclaimerTextStyle}>{this.props.usageTip}</Text>
        );
    }
```

But I am very confused why the first version of my code behaved like that? It was also very hard to find the problem because release build debugging is not very easy. (At least I don't know any easy way)

Comment: You have typo in your if statement: this.props.usageTip =! '' => should be this.props.usageTip != ''

Comment: Thanks, I just realised I had fixed it in the working version even the sample here is not fixed. I wonder why it worked on debug??

Comment: Do you have remote debugger enabled?

Comment: Yes. It worked fine with emulator and device when tried on debug build with debugs on. Now I might have idea what is happening. Because of the typo the if was interpret as assigning boolean value into this.props.usageTip. And the if was interpret as true on both debug and release build but the different might be that debug build does not allow component to assign value to this.props so the original value is not changed but on release build it allows the assinging. Not sure which behaviour is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When using React Native, you're going to be running your JavaScript code in two environments:

- In most cases, React Native will use JavaScriptCore, the JavaScript
  engine that powers Safari.
- When using Chrome debugging, all JavaScript code runs within Chrome
  itself, communicating with native code via WebSockets. Chrome uses V8
  as its JavaScript engine.

While both environments are very similar, you may end up hitting some inconsistencies.
[To get More Detail](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment)